# Cartoon aired on Kabillion: three boys get teleported to another dimension and get turned into a tiger and two robots

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This Kabillion cartoon was about three boys who got teleported to another dimension and got turned into a tiger, a yellow robot, and a tiny blue.

And they also turn into marbles and participate in races with the enemy.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brave_of_Gold_Goldran?

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120926225616AALvFVl

Comment: [Matchless Raijin-Oh](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2459)?